# How to locally add my charms to the juju-gui?

Tags: juju

I know there are something like this

```
export JUJU_REPOSITORY=/var/repository/charms
```

or charms can be deployed by drag and drop from desktop directly to the juju-gui canvas. But i mean how add my packages to the charm browser which are located on the left sidebar in juju-gui (or it is possible wihtout publishing to charm store)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add your charms to the left column, the Charm Browser, you need to create the appropriate repository in Launchpad ([step-by-step guide](https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/authors-charm-store)).

To deploy a local charm via the gui you need to zip up the contents of your charm in the correct directory structure for a charm and drag and drop that zip onto the canvas. It will then guide you through the process of deploying that charm to your environment.

Comment: I asked my question "how to show my local charms in the juju-gui charm browser" separately here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/646962/how-to-retrieve-and-list-local-charms-in-juju-gui-charm-browser.